# How to share user and user profile in a multisite environment?

Tags: 7, users, database, multi-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a multisite, sharing users and nodes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19517/how-do-i-create-a-multisite-sharing-users-and-nodes)
>   [How to share user and user profile in a multisite environment?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35839/how-to-share-user-and-user-profile-in-a-multisite-environment)

My question was about the whole process to get the shared user in a multisite environment.
I didn't know how to start.

I found my answer here

http://drupal.org/node/547862

As the title says I would like to share user and profile table between multisites.

I have got the main domain like example.com and then I have two subdomain site2.example.com and site3.example.com with separate db.

My 'sites' directory is:

**all**

modules

themes

libraries

---

**default**

files

setting.php

---

**site2.example.com**

modules

themes

libraries

files

setting.php

---

**site3.example.com**

modules

themes

libraries

files

setting.php

I know how to create multisites with separate db, modules, themes and files, now I would like to know the whole process to create a multisite with shared user and user profile.
What I need to do?

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Thanks Oswald, it was me, I had a problem during the submit. I already deleted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit settings.php -> $databases

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'database' => 'my_db',
  'username' => 'user',
  'password' => 'pass',
  'host' => 'example',
  'prefix' => array(
    'default'   => '',
    'users'     => 'shared_db_',
    'sessions'  => 'shared_db_',
    'role'      => 'shared_db_',
    'authmap'   => 'shared_db_',
  ),
  'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
);
```

Add any other tables as required in `prefix` array.
Have a look at settings.php as well it has lots of documentation on all these.

Comment: Thanks kantu, which settings.php? the default one or the one in the site2.example.com?

Comment: Which line is it? I've found different $databases...

Comment: Only 1 `$databases` will be there initially, you can add this in the end others are all examples in comments.

Comment: Hi Kantu, just to clearify, this is the first time I do it. I have 2 website and 2 db, db1 and db2. How do I write that array to make the site 2 use the user from db1? Thanks

Comment: Just put that in the end of settings.php of both sites and replace my_db, user, pass shared_db according to your setup. This way both sites will use `shared_db` database for users table, add any other tables if needed (profile_values, profile_fields) to the prefix array

Comment: ok, I will put both on setting.php but "my_db" will be the name of the main db or I should put db1 on the site1 setting and db2 on site2 setting? sorry for this but i cannot figure it out... shared_db_ is a function that says to share those table accross all the website?

Comment: Hi Kantu, I solved it, what I missed was the first configuration. I didn't know i should create a new db with the shared tables. Thanks, now I can understand the code you posted.

Comment: I still don't understand :( can someone enlighten me please...?