# Have a multisite instance use a single user session table

Tags: 8, users, multi-sites

I have a multisite drupal instance each with their own database but I want users to be logged in on all of them once they log into any one of them.

I found another question asking for something similar but it is for drupal 7 and it seems like it assumes each site is using the same database (I think)

[How to share user and user profile in a multisite environment?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35840/how-to-share-user-and-user-profile-in-a-multisite-environment)

I do see a 'sessions' table but I'm not sure how to make each site use the same one.

Comment: bakery module would probably work, but there is no drupal 8 version. cas would be another option.

Comment: You'd not want to do this. You'd want to use some sort of SSO solution, but I'm not sure what the way to do this in Drupal 8 would be...