# Shared subset of users in a multi-site instance

Tags: 7, users, multi-sites

Can I have a shared subset of users in a multi-site instance? In other words, I have the same list of administrators across all sites. Can these administrators be admins for all sites through a shared database rather than producing the same list of admins for each site?

- I am aware that each site in a multi-site instance has its own database, which contains content and users specific to said site.
- I am aware that content and users can be shared by [configuring a shared database](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/19519). However, I only want to share administrators among sites and keep content and other users with site-specific roles and permissions specific to its respective site.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned yourself you can share users across multiple site but that are **all** users. So you need an external 'database' for your admin users that magically exists for all sites.

For this you could use https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap which could contain you administrators.

Normal users can login as normal aka without use the LDAP directory.

Note LDAP can work with MS Active Directory too.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this would require users (in my case, administrators) to be on an LDAP instance, then authenticated on all sites in a multi-site instance using said LDAP instance? This may be the only way to go about it, so your suggestion is appreciated, but 1) I was hoping to keep it in-house (ie, within what is capable with Drupal) and 2) adding this external component seems to add complexity. Moreover, I'm not sure if adding this external component is possible in my case.

Comment: Bakery sound much easier for sure. For SSO maybe https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap_sso helps.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use what Drupal.org uses(d?), the [bakery module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bakery).  This requires the sites to be on the same sub-domain by default.

Comment: This has promise. Although users will be per site, SSO would allow my admins to sign in once on one site, then access another site without having to sign in again. Not sure this is the ultimate solution, but this does provide a way to connect admins across all sites.